# Liferay: how to retrieve layout from a layout set?

Tags: layout, jakarta-ee, portlet, liferay, portal

I'm trying to build a new navigation system based on myPlaces portlet. The aim is to show every page contained in each community/organization that can be accessed by the user.

I'm stuck on the Layout system. I retrieved the LayouSet of the community (both private and public), but I can't manage to retrieve the Layoust (which are actually the pages).

How can I do that? I hoped there would be simplye a getLayouts() from LayoutSet model, but there is nothing like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got it, I had to go through `LayoutLocalServiceUtil`:

```java
List<Layout> layouts =  LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayouts(group.getGroupId(), false);
```